# go back to the previous page of pdf while writing : itextsharp

Tags: c#, visual-studio, itext

I have a query on go back to previous page of pdf document while writing.

For example: now my contentbyte is writing on 5th page, that is the continuation of 3rd page means it should goto the 3rd page and write as this page continue in 5th page.

My question is how to navigate to previous page in itextsharp.

Comment: *How* do you write to your document? Are you using a `PdfWriter`? Or a `PdfCopy`? Or a `PdfStamper`? If you are using a `PdfWriter`, please be aware that this class flushes content to the output stream early; when the fifth page has been started, the third page usually is already stored away. If you know early that you will add something to page three, you merely are not sure what it will be, you can create a `PdfTemplate`, show it on page three, but wait until page five to draw content onto the template and flush it. If you don't know early, you could create such a template for each page or..

Comment: ... If you don't know early, you could create such a template for each page or use a `PdfStamper` to add those additions in a second run.

Comment: Sorry for delay reply....

Comment: i am using pdfwriter

Comment: later i came to know t hat content of output stream are flush early, then somehow i stored current page details in list, where currently cut and continue on another page and based on total height of the logic diagram, and my PDF page total size, calculate the future page number....while that page will enter based on the Y calculation it will put the continuation number

Comment: i used the calculation like:(overall height- current page used height) / my page total height... if the returned value is 0 or 0.7 above means next page..or else current page number+returned value ..is the page where is going to continue